# How to make selected modules from a directory available to Python?

Tags: python, python-importlib

Let's say I have a directory (outside Python path) full of Python modules and packages.

If I want to make all of them available to current Python interpreter, I could do `sys.path.append(dir_name)`.

How can I make only selected modules or packages from this directory available to Python and hide the rest?

I have considered creating a separate directory which contains symlinks to those selected modules, but I don't know how to make it cross-platform and it doesn't feel right.

I suspect the solution involves `importlib`, but I'm hoping to get more specific pointers.

Answer (score 0):

On a linux system I do the following:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/full/path/to/packages/packagename:$PYTHONPATH
```

What the above does:

- There is a global system variable which python uses. It allows for it look in this path for a module or relevant requirement when needed.

you may need to use the `bin/` directory of the package and you may also export it just to the PATH variable if that doesn't fully work.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, then in case where `packagename` sits in `/full/path/to/packages` one has to put `/full/path/to/packages` to PYTHONPATH, not `/full/path/to/packages/packagename`.

Comment: hmmm, did you try it? also I thought you wanted to use selected packages only, it this still the case?

Comment: Just in case, I did try. Not working. Yes, I need only selected packages.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution myself (works in Python 3.5 and later):

```
from importlib.machinery import PathFinder
from importlib.util import module_from_spec

def load_module_from_alternative_path(module_name, path):
    spec = PathFinder.find_spec(module_name, path)
    module = module_from_spec(spec)
    sys.modules[module_name] = module
    if spec.loader is not None:
        spec.loader.exec_module(module)

load_module_from_alternative_path("foo", ["path_containing_foo"])
import foo
```